# Is it the carrier's responsibility to bringing a passenger home?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, check-in

**Short story**

My girlfriend is currently on a business trip in India. Due to issues with her reservation, she is concerned she might have troubles checking in for the plane back home. However, seeing as she is mid-itinerary and on the return leg of the journey, is it the carrier's responsibility to bring her home, similar as to a passenger being denied entry to the destination country?

**Longer story**

Her trip is booked through a travel agency (company policy). The carrier is Lufthansa, but the operator for the first leg of the return journey is Air India (and later SAS).

Before departure, she noticed her ticket doesn't actually carry her exact name as in the passport but an abbreviated form (example: Kate instead of Catherine, except her name is uncommon in the English-speaking world). She was advised that the ticket could not be changed, so she would have to take her chances.

She did get to India, however presently she is not able to check in online for the return trip, as her reservation does not exist in the system (using the booking reference or any version of her name).

Lufthansa says they cannot help further, as the reservation was made through a travel agency, but points to the operator for check-in.
The operator (Air India) doesn't have her booking.

Normally, this would be an issue that should be contested at the airport, however apparently there is currently a security check at the entrance of the airport, and you will not be admitted without a printed ticket matching the passport.

The travel agency has advised her that she should either buy a new ticket, or take her chances that they will magically find her reservation at the airport.

They also say that in the event of problems (reservation cannot be found, or she is denied boarding due to naming issues), she should argue to the carrier that it is their responsibility to bring her back, as it is a return journey.

Comment: The explanation provided by the agency makes little sense, it's only a return journey if they assume there is a reservation, in which case they simply have an obligation to honor it. But there is no obligation for them to bring anyone home *per se*, not even when you are refused entry. How would that work? You prove you are German so you can demand to be put on a flight to Germany that you haven't booked? Or only on the carrier that brought you there, even if you booked a one-way ticket?

Comment: It is the same booking for the outbound and return journey. She has already flown the outbound flights, and all documentation shows the outbound and return flights as the same booking. The main issue is, that somewhere this booking got lost in the system, and now no one wants to take responsibility for it. So the question is, seeing as she has already travelled half of the flights, is it the carriers responsibility to uphold the rest of the flights?

Comment: Yes, I got that but it still makes little sense to look at it that way. Either they accept there is a booking based on whatever documentation you have and everything is fine. Or they don't and there is no obligation arising from the earlier flights. The only obligation comes from the fact that she did book and pay for those flights in the first place, computer glitch notwithstanding. It would work the same way if it was the first leg of the trip or maybe some intermediate leg that would not bring her back to her place of residence.

Comment: Does she have her boarding pass for the outbound journey?

Comment: @phoog Yes, she has outbound boarding pass on her phone.

Comment: Has she tried showing that to the airline to help them find her reservation?

Comment: @phoog Nope, not yet. Her flight is not until tomorrow. The ticket has her name and reservation number, which the airline uses to find her booking. She actually has received a new ticket from the travel agency. This will allow her at least to enter the airport, where she will hopefully be able to check in with her actual ticket (the new one will be cancelled, it's just to get in to the airport, as they require her to present a valid ticket).

Comment: Travel agents still exist only because they are able to sort out issues like this. She should contact the travel agent and get them to confirm that the reservation they made is still valid, and if they are not sure about that the travel agent should book another flight at their expense.

Comment: @Nix, Other than the name issue the paper ticket was probably unnecessary, I've always flown from India with non-paper e-tickets and used a paper copy of the itinerary to get into the terminal. FWIW On my one flight out with Air India,  booked through United, I also couldn't find my reservation at the Air India web site using the UA locator but the check-in desk did know who I was.

Comment: Typo on names are very very frequent, see many similar question in this site. Don't worry. I think what matter more is the passport number on the registration system. You can check in Lufthansa site, and ev. change it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi how can she check or change anything online if she cannot retrieve the reservation online?  Also, I'm skeptical of your assertion about the passport number.  Every reservation lookup I've ever done has been by name; passport details are not usually required at booking; and furthermore I routinely use different passports for different portions of the same booking without this ever having been a problem (indeed, I don't remember anyone even so much as commenting on it).

Comment: Can she find the booking using the Lufthansa reference on [Classic CheckMyTrip](https://classic.checkmytrip.com/plnext/XCMTXXNS/StartOver.action;?LANGUAGE=GB&SITE=XCMTXXNS)? If she can, then she should look up the e-ticket number and provide that to the airline. If she can't, make sure she is using the Lufthansa reference, which may be different to the Travel Agent reference.

Comment: Second, the confusion may be caused because Air India uses a different computer reservation system to Lufthansa. Therefore Lufthansa will have an Amadeus record, which might only contain its flights, and the Air India flights will be on Sabre, and that might only contain the AI flights. Somewhere there will be a master PNR created by the travel agent, which could be on a third system. You may want to ask the travel agent for *all* the PNRs involved in this journey.

Comment: @Relaxed; the Warsaw Convention on air travel explicitly imposes an obligation on all carriers to return a passenger who is refused entry back to his or her starting point. Company policies do not affect this.

Comment: @TimLymington Starting point, yes, home, no. I am well aware of this but it's an obligation towards the state refusing entry, what it is about is getting that state rid of unwanted people (and giving airlines some incentive to check documents), not a convenience to the passenger. Pretty much the opposite of what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I wrote as comment, typos on names are very very frequent, but to answer you:

No; the airline will transport you to destination, if you comply to rules.  Failing such rules, there are no more obligation from your airline.

Missing passports, tickets, etc. are some reasons, but also health reason (also if you just fall in the stair on airport) (or drunken). Also governments could restrict you (or your airlines) to carry people in a certain zone. Natural disasters and wars also cancel obligation of your airlines. They doesn't need to provide you alternative transportation.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that her ticket carry a different name is unfortunate, but it is not the main issue. The issue is, that after travelling to the destination, the booking seemingly has ceased to exist. The argument from the travel agency has been, that seeing as the carrier has already flown her two of the four flights, it must be a valid booking, and the carrier are obligated to resolve it. Obviously, the carrier claims no responsibility, as they are not operating the flight, and the operator doesn't feel responsible for a booking that (for some reason) does not exist in their system.

Comment: @Nix: Did you check in Lufthansa website. They should have all itinerary. Note: the web system is different to client support: the first works for all people (but ev. some changes are blocked), the second one requires that you bought ticket with them.

Comment: Lufthansa does not allow checkin, as they are not operating this particular flight. They also do not allow ticket changes, as the booking was not made through them directly. The itinerary is there, though - it just does not exist in Air India's systems, who are operating the flight.